# How do I check that a project manifest is complete in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to make sure that the `manifest.toml` file for my Julia project is complete such that the results of my project can be reproduced by anyone. I know I can use Travis or any other clean environment but I am looking for a native Julia based solution if possible.

Question originally posted [here](https://julialang.slack.com/archives/C67EFTEF3/p1569187627050300).

Comment: Bbbbut... that was my question! :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Navigate to the project folder.
2. `export JULIA_LOAD_PATH=.` (or `set JULIA_LOAD_PATH=.` on Windows)
3. Start `julia`.
4. `] instantiate` the project
5. Run you project code (most importantly the `using` statements).

This way, julia will exclusively use the packages (and versions) as specified in the project's toml files. In particular, you will get errors for every package that doesn't exist.

**Background**: the `LOAD_PATH` (called `JULIA_LOAD_PATH` outside of Julia) variable specifies a stack of paths pointing to Julia environments. As per default, it contains three entries,

```
julia> LOAD_PATH
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "@"
 "@v#.#"
 "@stdlib"
```

which expand to the current active environment (`@`) the general, say, `v.1.2` environment (`@v#.#`) and so on (see [`? LOAD_PATH`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/constants/#Base.LOAD_PATH) for more details). If a piece of code tries to `using` or `import` a package, Julia will look for it in the toml files in those directories in order (from top to bottom). This means that one can generally load a package `X` that is only present in the `v.1.2` environment but not in the current project (i.e. the project isn't self contained). By the procedure above we drop those paths from the `LOAD_PATH` variable and only keep the current project environment.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. `Pkg` should make a command to check this more easily...